# How to make bundle from subdirectory contain javascript file

Tags: webpack, gulp

Currently I am stuck with the following situation.Following is my folder structure.

```
-Root
--Products
    --Product_1
         -- Product_1.html
         -- Product_1.js
         -- Product_1.css    
    --Product_2
         -- Product_2.html
         -- Product_2.js
         -- Product_2.css    
    --Product_3
         -- Product_3.html
         -- Product_3.js
         -- Product_3.css    
    --Product_4
         -- Product_4.html
         -- Product_4.js
         -- Product_4.css
```

Now I want to create combine bundle of all the .js files available in Products folder and create one bundle.js using either gulp and/or webpack.

Anyone have any idea how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) to combine all JS files. For your folder structure you need following code.

```
var gulp = require ("gulp"),
    concat = require ("gulp-concat");

gulp.task ("concatJs", function () {
    return gulp.src ("./Products/*/*.js")
            .pipe (concat ("bundle.js"))
            .pipe (gulp.dest ("./Products/"));
});
```

- In gulp.src target all JS files inside sub-folders of the Products folder (Products/*/*.js)